# How to create work item in VSO project using PowerShell

Tags: rest, powershell, azure-devops

How can I create new work item in Visual Studio Online project using rest API. Here is my expectation as described [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/wit/work-items#Createaworkitem)

```
$task = @{"op"="test task";"path"="/rev";"value"=1}
$json = $task | ConvertTo-Json
$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apihref/wit/workitems/$Task?api-version=1.0 -Body $json -headers $h -Method PATCH
```

but it generates error: `Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.`

Comment: You have the hash `$task` in your URI, that doesn't look correct. The uri should be a string

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it. First of all, I need screening symbol **`** before $Task. Second, I have to use array of fields (does non like one fields)

$wi = @(@{"op"= "add"; "path"= "/fields/System.Title";"value"="test task from REST API"}
    ,@{"op"= "add"; "path"= "/fields/System.AssignedTo";"value"="Andrew Butenko"})

$json = @($wi) | ConvertTo-Json

$response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri "$($collectionHref)/$($projectName)/_apis/wit/workitems/`$Task?api-version=1.0" -Body $json -headers $h -Method PATCH -ContentType "application/json-patch+json"